# Creating a button in Access to to open a word document

Tags: ms-access, ms-word

I have a word document that uses mail merge feature and gets its information from the access db. When I use this code it does not open the word document with the current information. It opens the word document with the last saved information.

If I open the word document on its own, from the task bar, it asks if I want to run the SQL and I click yes and everything operates normally. I want to click a button from within access to accomplish this same task to open the contract.

Here is the code I used:

```
Private Sub Command205_Click()

Dim LWordDoc As String
Dim oApp As Object

'Path to the word document
LWordDoc = "C:\Users\.....k Up\01- Proposal\contract.docx"

If Dir(LWordDoc) = "" Then
  MsgBox "Document not found."

Else
  'Create an instance of MS Word
  Set oApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
  oApp.Visible = True

  'Open the Document
  oApp.Documents.Open FileName:=LWordDoc
End If

End Sub
```

***I should add that I am not a coder and know nothing about VBA, I copied this from this website so any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated. If you can provide me with coding or enough guidance to get me on the way would be great. Thank you

Comment: Take a look at the following link... there is sample code that I think will do what you want...  http://www.minnesotaithub.com/2015/11/automatic-mail-merge-with-vba-and-access/

Comment: I would recomment remove all mail merge information from template, leave just merge fields. Then in VBA code you create new MailMerge object in word document as proposed in comment above and generate merged documents - no questions asked. If you want to automatically close template document, clear MailMerge object, save template and then exit, otherwise template always will ask about saving the document before closing despite of NoSave parameter in Close method.

Comment: ok I should add I am a novice and got this code from this site so I simply copied and pasted things. all that was mentioned went over my head is there a simple way of doing things?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484268/update-linked-fields-in-word-document-from-excel-vba

Comment: I tried trying to relate what your link is to but cant get it to work. Is it really a huge task for access to open a file that already has a mail merge in place and simply update the current information? I'm seeing all kind of code that makes no sense to me from a few lines to a few hundred lines.

Comment: @Clueless-Al, it would help if you either tag a responder or state which link you are referring to ... there are two links mentioned... mine relates to Access, the other to Excel.  And did you try to follow the instructions at that link?

Comment: @Wayne G. Dunn..Sorry new to this so not sure how to tag but wayne G. Dunn I tried both and nada. I cant seem to come up with something that works. The farthest I have gotten and working is 1) creating the button 2) opening the file I want. The last part is to open the file and have it run the SQL command (SELECT * FROM 'Contract Information'), which pops up whenever I open the file "normally" from the task bar

Answer (score 2):

This code will run in Access to open a Mail Merge document and update content and save.

Using the link I originally posted (http://www.minnesotaithub.com/2015/11/automatic-mail-merge-with-vba-and-access/), I made a couple of modifications and was able to get that code to work.

I needed to add: ReadOnly:=True, _  to prevent a sharing violation
and I changed the Table Name of the source data.

NOTE!! You will need to change sode marked with'###' as follows:

###-1 Change to specify the full path of your TEMPLATE!!!

###-2 Change the SQLSTATEMENT to specify your recordsource!!!

Paste this code into your form,  make sure you have a Command Button Click Event that executes (Either rename 'Command205' in this code, or change your control name).

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command205_Click()
Dim strWordDoc  As String

    'Path to the word document of the Mail Merge
    '###-1 CHANGE THE FOLLOWING LINE TO POINT TO YOUR DOCUMENT!!
    strWordDoc = "C:\Users\.....k Up\01- Proposal\contract.docx"

    ' Call the code to merge the latest info
    startMerge strWordDoc

End Sub


'----------------------------------------------------
' Auto Mail Merge With VBA and Access (Early Binding)
'----------------------------------------------------
' NOTE: To use this code, you must reference
' The Microsoft Word 14.0 (or current version)
' Object Library by clicking menu Tools > References
' Check the box for:
' Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library in Word 2010
' Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library in Word 2013
' Click OK
'----------------------------------------------------
Function startMerge(strDocPath As String)
    Dim oWord           As Word.Application
    Dim oWdoc           As Word.Document
    Dim wdInputName     As String
    Dim wdOutputName    As String
    Dim outFileName     As String

    ' Set Template Path
    wdInputName = strDocPath            ' was CurrentProject.Path & "\mail_merge.docx"

    ' Create unique save filename with minutes and seconds to prevent overwrite
    outFileName = "MailMergeFile_" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddmms")

    ' Output File Path w/outFileName
    wdOutputName = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & outFileName

    Set oWord = New Word.Application
    Set oWdoc = oWord.Documents.Open(wdInputName)

    ' Start mail merge

    '###-2 CHANGE THE SQLSTATEMENT AS NEEDED
    With oWdoc.MailMerge
        .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
        .OpenDataSource _
            Name:=CurrentProject.FullName, _
            ReadOnly:=True, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
            LinkToSource:=True, _
            Connection:="QUERY mailmerge", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [tblEmployee]"         ' Change the table name or your query
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With

    ' Hide Word During Merge
    oWord.Visible = False

    ' Save file as PDF
    ' Uncomment the line below and comment out
    ' the line below "Save file as Word Document"
    '------------------------------------------------
    'oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 wdOutputName & ".pdf", 17

    ' Save file as Word Document
    ' ###-3 IF YOU DON'T WANT TO SAVE AS A NEW NAME, COMMENT OUT NEXT LINE
    oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 wdOutputName & ".docx", 16

    ' SHOW THE DOCUMENT
    oWord.Visible = True

    ' Close the template file
    If oWord.Documents(1).FullName = strDocPath Then
        oWord.Documents(1).Close savechanges:=False
    ElseIf oWord.Documents(2).FullName = strDocPath Then
        oWord.Documents(2).Close savechanges:=False
    Else
        MsgBox "Well, this should never happen! Only expected two documents to be open"
    End If

    ' Quit Word to Save Memory
    'oWord.Quit savechanges:=False

    ' Clean up memory
    '------------------------------------------------
    Set oWord = Nothing
    Set oWdoc = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129602/discussion-on-answer-by-wayne-g-dunn-creating-a-button-in-access-to-to-open-a-w).

Comment: Np, I'll clean these comments now.