# I want functionality to a button in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am having difficulties having a button perform what I want. I have an MS Access db which I input all of the information for a particular project. I also have a contract word document which is mail merged with this db.

So far with the help of some of you I've gotten this far (code below). It works, but if I have 120 records when the button is pressed it creates a long contract with all 120 records. I simply want to have just the current record (the record on my screen at the time) to only make a pdf.

I would also like to name the pdf which is created use a naming convention such as, "Name of product - Name of client". Both are fields in the record.

I want to add I am not a coder by no stretch of the imagination, kudos to you all that do this everyday....you are unsung heros.

---

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command205_Click()
Dim strWordDoc  As String

    'Path to the word document of the Mail Merge
    '###-1 CHANGE THE FOLLOWING LINE TO POINT TO YOUR DOCUMENT!!
    strWordDoc = "C:\Users\...\Google Drive\contract.docx"

    ' Call the code to merge the latest info
    startMerge strWordDoc

End Sub


'----------------------------------------------------
' Auto Mail Merge With VBA and Access (Early Binding)
'----------------------------------------------------
' NOTE: To use this code, you must reference
' The Microsoft Word 14.0 (or current version)
' Object Library by clicking menu Tools > References
' Check the box for:
' Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library in Word 2010
' Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library in Word 2013
' Click OK
'----------------------------------------------------
Function startMerge(strDocPath As String)
    Dim oWord           As Word.Application
    Dim oWdoc           As Word.Document
    Dim wdInputName     As String
    Dim wdOutputName    As String
    Dim outFileName     As String

    ' Set Template Path
    wdInputName = strDocPath            ' was CurrentProject.Path & "\mail_merge.docx"

    ' Create unique save filename with minutes and seconds to prevent overwrite
    outFileName = "[Product Name]_" & Format(Now(), "mmddyyyy")

    ' Output File Path w/outFileName
    wdOutputName = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & outFileName

    Set oWord = New Word.Application
    Set oWdoc = oWord.Documents.Open(wdInputName)

    ' Start mail merge

    '###-2 CHANGE THE SQLSTATEMENT AS NEEDED
    With oWdoc.MailMerge
        .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
        .OpenDataSource _
            Name:=CurrentProject.FullName, _
            ReadOnly:=True, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
            LinkToSource:=True, _
            Connection:="QUERY mailmerge", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Contract Information]"   ' Change the table name or your query"
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With

    ' Hide Word During Merge
    oWord.Visible = False

    ' Save file as PDF
    ' Uncomment the line below and comment out
    ' the line below "Save file as Word Document"
    '------------------------------------------------
    oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 wdOutputName & ".pdf", 17

    ' Save file as Word Document
    ' ###-3 IF YOU DON'T WANT TO SAVE AS A NEW NAME, COMMENT OUT NEXT LINE
    'oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 wdOutputName & ".docx", 16

    ' SHOW THE DOCUMENT
    oWord.Visible = True

    ' Close the template file
    If oWord.Documents(1).FullName = strDocPath Then
        oWord.Documents(1).Close savechanges:=False
    ElseIf oWord.Documents(2).FullName = strDocPath Then
        oWord.Documents(2).Close savechanges:=False
    Else
        MsgBox "Well, this should never happen! Only expected two documents to be open"
    End If

    ' Quit Word to Save Memory
    'oWord.Quit savechanges:=False

    ' Clean up memory
    '------------------------------------------------
    Set oWord = Nothing
    Set oWdoc = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: This reeks of a *"I WANTS DA CODEZ"* question and if you have had *"the help of some of you"* then those so called *"helpers"* have given you a false expectation of what we do here at [so]. Please before asking questions like this go away and review [ask] and perhaps provide a [mcve]. Once you have done this, [edit] the question to reflect these guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the *SQL* to return only the current Id:

```
SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Contract Information] Where ProjectId = " & Me!ProjectId.Value & ""
```

and adjust *outFileName* to reflect "Name of product - Name of client":

```
outFileName = Me!ProductName.Value & " - " & Me!ClientName.Value
```

Comment: using this filter still pulls every single record and creates a contract with all records. I have a field called "ID" in my tables which is unique. here is what I've done.

SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Contract Information] Where Id = " & Me!ProjectId.Value & ""

Comment: If you filter on one id only, it can't pull all projects, so something else is going on.

Comment: what do you think is going on. the complete code is listed

Comment: Hard to tell. I have neither your document nor your data.

Comment: @Clueless-Al, you abandoned this same question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40879759/creating-a-button-in-access-to-to-open-a-word-document). As for this thread, no, your posted code does NOT show any filter of the recordset. We all know that a proper filter will work, so do the following: (1) Open your table. (2) Write down that key of any record. (3) Create a query in design view using the SQL as shown by Gustav, but use your key in the criteria field. (4) Run it and you will get 1 record returned.

Comment: I got it to work I just had to make a couple of changes. Thank you so much.

Comment: @wayne  It works but it does not close the process running in the background. I have to go into task manager and end task. Do you have an idea on how to end that without going into task manager? Thank you

Comment: Yeah, I had mentioned that in the other post, but have since deleted those comments to clean up the mess.  Uncomment line:   'oWord.Quit savechanges:=False

Comment: @wayne-I didnt do anything I think a moderator did that and put the whole conversation into a private chat. I will try this now

Comment: How do I make  the PDF save to a certain location on my computer?
C:\Users\.....\01- Proposal\Temp Contracts

Comment: Look for the line >' Output File Path w/outFileName< then change the next line to whatever you want the path/name to be.